# Apache httpd 2.x necessary modules

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd

I have the following list of modules in my Apache httpd installation by default, but I'm pretty sure that I don't need (at least) a few of them. So, my question is what are the *Necessary* modules for Apache httpd to work properly?

I'm running a LAMP server on a CentOS 6, running only a website (SaaS), nothing more. So, I'm looking to load only the truly necessary modules.

Here is the loaded modules on my installation by default:

```
auth_basic_module
auth_digest_module
authn_file_module
authn_alias_module
authn_anon_module
authn_dbm_module
authn_default_module
authz_host_module
authz_user_module
authz_owner_module
authz_groupfile_module
authz_dbm_module
authz_default_module
ldap_module
authnz_ldap_module
include_module
log_config_module
logio_module
env_module
ext_filter_module
mime_magic_module
expires_module
deflate_module
headers_module
usertrack_module
setenvif_module
mime_module
dav_module
status_module
autoindex_module
info_module
dav_fs_module
vhost_alias_module
negotiation_module
dir_module
actions_module
speling_module
userdir_module
alias_module
substitute_module
rewrite_module
proxy_module
proxy_balancer_module
proxy_ftp_module
proxy_http_module
proxy_ajp_module
proxy_connect_module
cache_module
suexec_module
disk_cache_module
cgi_module
version_module
```

As a *Hint*, again I'm not looking for a specific answer regarding to my machine's configuration. I want to know which modules are primary for Apache httpd?

Comment: There is no way for anyone to answer what is "truly necessary" -- everyone's definition will be different.  For example, I have no use for `mod_speling` or `mod_userdir`, but I could not live without `mod_status` output. The only way to answer your question is "You need all the modules your system uses to serve requests"

Comment: @voretaq7 thanks for the comment, but I can't believe that there is no way to answer this question. If all the modules are optional, so the answer is you can unload all the modules. If there is module X that if you unload it, you will face some major or minor issues, like security or performance related stuff, then, I'd say those are necessary for httpd.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, CentOS 6 has quite long list of Apache2 modules installed by default. I found that many of them are not necessary (at least for applications that I host).

In general I like to start with modules that Debian distro loads by default (which is much shorter than this from CentOS):

> core_module (static)
>
> log_config_module (static)
>
> logio_module (static)
>
> mpm_prefork_module (static)
>
> http_module (static)
>
> so_module (static)
>
> alias_module (shared)
>
> auth_basic_module (shared)
>
> authn_file_module (shared)
>
> authz_default_module (shared)
>
> authz_groupfile_module (shared)
>
> authz_host_module (shared)
>
> authz_user_module (shared)
>
> autoindex_module (shared)
>
> cgi_module (shared)
>
> deflate_module (shared)
>
> dir_module (shared)
>
> env_module (shared)
>
> mime_module (shared)
>
> negotiation_module (shared)
>
> perl_module (shared)
>
> php5_module (shared)
>
> python_module (shared)
>
> reqtimeout_module (shared)
>
> rewrite_module (shared)
>
> setenvif_module (shared)
>
> status_module (shared)

and then unload those that are unecessary for me:

> perl_module
>
> python_module
>
> cgi_module
>
> autoindex_module

and one that should be loaded only for troubleshooting/tunning Apache:

> status_module

Also I suspect that following modules are unnecessary for me but I'm not 100% sure (I would have to check) so I keep them for now:

> reqtimeout_module
>
> negotation_module
>
> dir_module

It is also interesting to investigate with [this](http://www.pixelbeat.org/scripts/ps_mem.py) script how unloading modules affects memory consumption by the Apache.